# How do you automate tagging using a Lambda function on AWS?

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, tagging

I'm trying to automate tagging for the following resources on AWS:

- Amazon RDS
- Amazon DynamoDB
- Amazon Image AMI
- Amazon EC2 Instance
- Amazon Lambda Function
- Amazon RDS Snapshot
- Amazon RDS Security
- Amazon RDS Subnet
- Amazon Route 53 Hosted
- Amazon S3 Bucket
- Amazon CloudFormation

Currently I have a Lambda function that is almost identical to this article: [How to Automatically Tag Amazon EC2 Resources in Response to API Events | AWS Security Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-automatically-tag-amazon-ec2-resources-in-response-to-api-events/)

How can I modify this Lambda function so it tags the above resources as well?

I've tried finding documentation on how to tag these specific resources and I can't seem to find anything that's relevant to tagging using a Lambda function.

```
elif eventname == 'CreateImage':
    ids.append(detail['responseElements']['imageId'])
    logger.info(ids)

elif eventname == 'CreateSnapshot':
    ids.append(detail['responseElements']['snapshotId'])
    logger.info(ids)
elif eventname == 'CreateSecurityGroup':
    ids.append(detail['responseElements']['groupId'])
else:
    logger.warning('Not supported action')
```

The above code is adding tags for EC2, but we need it to add tags to the resources I listed above.

Answer (score 3):

This should help on a few of them.

Here are the cloudwatch event patterns:

```
{
  "detail-type": [
    "AWS API Call via CloudTrail"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": [
      "ec2.amazonaws.com",
      "rds.amazonaws.com",
      "lambda.amazonaws.com",
      "s3.amazonaws.com",
      "dynamodb.amazonaws.com",
      "elasticfilesystem.amazonaws.com"
    ],
    "eventName": [
      "CreateVolume",
      "RunInstances",
      "CreateImage",
      "CreateSnapshot",
      "CreateDBInstance",
      "CreateFunction20150331",
      "UpdateFunctionConfiguration20150331v2",
      "UpdateFunctionCode20150331v2",
      "CreateBucket",
      "CreateTable",
      "CreateMountTarget"
    ]
  }
}
```

and then here is the corresponding lambda code which will need a few modifications for your environment.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import json
import boto3
import logging
import time
import datetime

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    logger.info('################  Event: ############## ' + str(event))
    #print('Received event: ' + json.dumps(event, indent=2))

    ids = []

    try:
        region = event['region']
        detail = event['detail']
        eventname = detail['eventName']
        arn = detail['userIdentity']['arn']
        principal = detail['userIdentity']['principalId']
        userType = detail['userIdentity']['type']

        if userType == 'IAMUser':
            user = detail['userIdentity']['userName']

        else:
            user = principal.split(':')[1]


        logger.info('principalId: ' + str(principal))
        logger.info('region: ' + str(region))
        logger.info('eventName: ' + str(eventname))
        logger.info('detail: ' + str(detail))

        ec2_client = boto3.resource('ec2')
        lambda_client = boto3.client('lambda')
        rds_client = boto3.client('rds')
        s3_client = boto3.resource('s3')
        ddb_client = boto3.client('dynamodb')
        efs_client = boto3.client('efs')

        if eventname == 'CreateVolume':
            ids.append(detail['responseElements']['volumeId'])
            logger.info(ids)

        elif eventname == 'RunInstances':
            items = detail['responseElements']['instancesSet']['items']
            for item in items:
                ids.append(item['instanceId'])
            logger.info(ids)
            logger.info('number of instances: ' + str(len(ids)))

            base = ec2_client.instances.filter(InstanceIds=ids)

            #loop through the instances
            for instance in base:
                for vol in instance.volumes.all():
                    ids.append(vol.id)
                for eni in instance.network_interfaces:
                    ids.append(eni.id)

        elif eventname == 'CreateImage':
            ids.append(detail['responseElements']['imageId'])
            logger.info(ids)

        elif eventname == 'CreateSnapshot':
            ids.append(detail['responseElements']['snapshotId'])
            logger.info(ids)

        elif eventname == 'CreateFunction20150331':
            try:
                functionArn = detail['responseElements']['functionArn']
                lambda_client.tag_resource(Resource=functionArn,Tags={'CreatedBy': user})
                lambda_client.tag_resource(Resource=functionArn,Tags={'DateCreated': time.strftime("%B %d %Y")})
            except Exception as e:
                logger.error('Exception thrown at CreateFunction20150331' + str(e))
                pass
        elif eventname == 'UpdateFunctionConfiguration20150331v2':
            try:
                functionArn = detail['responseElements']['functionArn']
                lambda_client.tag_resource(Resource=functionArn,Tags={'LastConfigModifiedByNetID': user})
            except Exception as e:
                logger.error('Exception thrown at UpdateFunctionConfiguration20150331v2' + str(e))
                pass
        elif eventname == 'UpdateFunctionCode20150331v2':
            try:
                functionArn = detail['responseElements']['functionArn']
                lambda_client.tag_resource(Resource=functionArn,Tags={'LastCodeModifiedByNetID': user})
            except Exception as e:
                logger.error('Exception thrown at UpdateFunctionCode20150331v2' + str(e))
                pass
        elif eventname == 'CreateDBInstance':
            try:
                dbResourceArn = detail['responseElements']['dBInstanceArn']
                rds_client.add_tags_to_resource(ResourceName=dbResourceArn,Tags=[{'Key':'CreatedBy','Value': user}])
            except Exception as e:
                logger.error('Exception thrown at CreateDBInstance' + str(e))
                pass
        elif eventname == 'CreateBucket':
            try:
                bucket_name = detail['requestParameters']['bucketName']
                s3_client.BucketTagging(bucket_name).put(Tagging={'TagSet': [{'Key':'CreatedBy','Value': user}]})
            except Exception as e:
                logger.error('Exception thrown at CreateBucket' + str(e))
                pass
        elif eventname == 'CreateTable':
            try:
                tableArn = detail['responseElements']['tableDescription']['tableArn']
                ddb_client.tag_resource(ResourceArn=tableArn,Tags=[{'Key':'CreatedBy','Value': user}])
            except Exception as e:
                logger.error('Exception thrown at CreateTable' + str(e))
                pass
        elif eventname == 'CreateMountTarget':
            try:
                system_id = detail['requestParameters']['fileSystemId']
                efs_client.create_tags(FileSystemId=system_id, Tags=[{'Key':'CreatedBy','Value': user}])
            except Exception as e:
                logger.error('Exception thrown at CreateMountTarget' + str(e))
                pass
        # todo: EMR and Glacier also possible candidates
        else:
            logger.warning('No matching eventname found in the Auto Tag lambda function (Ln 118)')

        if ids:
            for resourceid in ids:
                print('Tagging resource ' + resourceid)
            ec2_client.create_tags(Resources=ids, Tags=[{'Key': 'CreatedBy', 'Value': user}])

        logger.info(' Remaining time (ms): ' + str(context.get_remaining_time_in_millis()) + '\n')
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error('Something went wrong: ' + str(e))
        return False
```

You are kind of limited by what is supported by Cloudwatch events, but this will hopefully help you knock out a few of the ones on your list.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I'll start testing your script out and see what happens.

Comment: Our environment already had a cloudformation stack to automate tagging EC2. I tried adding your code to our current Lambda Function and modifying the CloudWatch rule. I still can't automate tagging. Do you know what I might be doing wrong? Would I have to create an entire new CloudFormation stack for this to work properly?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something from python boto lib would help (on example of RDS) :

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/rds.html#RDS.Client.add_tags_to_resource

```
response = client.add_tags_to_resource(
ResourceName='arn:aws:rXXXXX,
Tags=[
{
'Key': 'Staging',
'Value': '2019',
},
], )
```

Answer (score 0):

To tag resources upon creation you need to use Lambda, Cloudwatch events and some automation.

You can tag resources with the IAM ARN of the resource creator and resource created-date with the documentation available [here](https://github.com/GorillaStack/auto-tag), this is an open-source tagging solution for AWS. 
This will help you  tag your resources with the IAM ARN of the creator and the resource created-date.

There are two ways you can implement the solution available on the above link, 
1. Shell Script and 
2. CloudFormation template.